# Is there an elegant way to sort by a hash map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, hash

I have a hash with labeled numbered questions `(the keys)`, and five possible answers `(the values)`

```
questions = {
  likert_1:  %w(choice_5mMP0CMR9tC choice_6kUil9z7wi4 choice_6ZQQ7c2KR3O choice_6ilb652FCqZ choice_6Z3NYElYPPM),
  likert_2:  %w(choice_5pjBFzoqqpc choice_6AARUgqxvGL choice_5lnoEM7GUYr choice_5inpB7UT9Bs choice_6N6ETdSVpFP)
}
```

The database is saving per user, *one* value per question. So the database could have any combination of one value per each `likert_#` . **But!** the database will not save them in the order they were answered.

Therefore, I am trying to find an elegant way to sort any given two responses by how they are ordered `likert_1` before `likert_2`

So if I had : `[choice_5pjBFzoqqpc choice_5mMP0CMR9tC]` . Then they should be returned reversed as : `[choice_5mMP0CMR9tC, choice_5pjBFzoqqpc]` because `choice_5mMP0CMR9tC` appears in `likert_1` and `choice_5pjBFzoqqpc` appears in `likert_2`.

Comment: How are the responses stored?

Comment: As an `Answer` object, where the attribute `answer` contains for example `choice_5mMP0CMR9tC`. I can access an array of choices by doing `@answers.map(&:answer)`

Comment: Is there a reason the timestamps are not in order? Depending on the scale of data you're handling, sorting could be a very expensive operation.

Comment: a database will never save data in order, the order you retrieve data from the db is dependent on the order you ask it for and based upon the value of some field, if your data field is too big or not alpanumeric you 'd better provide sorting data in a separate field

Comment: So you have a collection of `Answer` objects and you do not know what keys they belong to? Cause if you know the keys you should be able to sort them accordingly. Maybe you need to post your `Answer` object, otherwise it is really hard to understand your problem.

Comment: Can't you just do the ordering directly during the query in the database instead? Something like `SELECT answer.* WHERE answer.question_id = question.id ORDER BY question.order`. Or whatever attribute of question to sort on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I also pointed out as a comment, it is probably much more efficient and more elegant to do the ordering in the query that retrieves the answers instead of afterwards. Since you have `Answer` and (presumably) `Question` tables, and a relationship between `Answer` and `Question` you can just order on your desired `Question` attribute in the query using an ORDER BY.

Having said that; since you asked about ordering the `Array` containing answers based on the order of the questions in the provided `Hash` and nobody answered yet, I will answer that question.

The simple idea here is to find the index of the question that contains the answer as one of its choices and use that index as the `sort_by` attribute. You can do that in the following way:

```
answers = ["choice_5pjBFzoqqpc", "choice_5mMP0CMR9tC"]

question_choices = questions.values
sorted = answers.sort_by { |a| question_choices.find_index { |c| c.include? a } }
# ["choice_5mMP0CMR9tC", "choice_5pjBFzoqqpc"]
```

Comment: This works great. There actually is no Question table, and I would only be sorting at most 10 answers per page, so its not entirely "expensive" per se. Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough then, glad I could help!